# Signup after user subscribe/purchase a product of stripe

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I am building a app where public users can view a pricing page and they can click on any plan (I am using stripe for subscriptions). upon clicking on that user will be redirected to checkout.
I want the user who has paid/subscribed to be redirected back to my app for registration. How can I check if this particular user has paid?

Comment: Without any context to your code, no one can answer.  We can help you fix your code, we can't write it for you.
Please see:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: buddy i didn't ask to write code for me. I just needed advice/flow to achieve this and rest I can do on my own. See below answer of Pompey.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your Checkout Session, you can add `{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}` to your `success_url`. Stripe will replace that template variable with the Checkout Session's actual ID. When the user navigates to your success page for registration, you can retrieve the Checkout Session by its id[2] on your server and check that its `payment_status` is `paid`.

```
session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
  success_url="http://yoursite.com/order/success?session_id=. 
  {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
  # other options...,
)
```

It is important to note that the customer's connection can cut out after they have made their payment but before they get to your success page. In that case a customer would pay you but not be able to register. To prevent that, Stripe recommends you also create a webhook endpoint[3] and listen for `checkout.session.completed` event. That way, you can email your customers a link to their registration page after they have paid so that they can get to it after payment.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders